# print sum of data members of child classes in parent function

Tags: c++, class, parent

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Fruit {

protected:
int nr_fruits = 0;

public:
void printTotal() {
    cout << "Total fruits in the basket: " << nr_fruits << endl;
}

};


class Mango : public Fruit {

int nr_mangoes;

public:

void getMango(int x) {
    nr_mangoes = x;
    cout << "There are " << nr_mangoes  << " mangoes in the basket" <<  endl;
    nr_fruits = nr_fruits + nr_mangoes;

}
};

class Apple : public Fruit {

int nr_apples;

public:

void getApple(int x) {
    nr_apples = x;
    cout << "There are " << nr_apples << " apples in the basket" <<  endl;
    nr_fruits = nr_fruits + nr_apples;
}
};



int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

Apple a1;
Mango m1;

a1.getApple(10);
a1.printTotal();
m1.getMango(20);
m1.printTotal();

return 0;
```

}

I need to make a function in the parent class Fruit, to be able to print the number of total fruits, in my case, nr_mangoes + nr_apples.

Obviously, the way i do it, the nr_fruits variable will output only the amount of mangoes or the amount of apples as the total amount of fruit.

How can i get to access the data members of the child classes, or make the variable nr_fruits so that it keeps the value throughout the program.

Comment: I fear you have a serious misunderstand how all of this works... Think about what creating another instance of the Apple class means to the data members (how many instances of them are there then?)?

Comment: What is the text of the actual *problem* you were trying to solve? I ask because this has a *very* strong aroma of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where your question is about how your *answer* can be "fixed", but in reality is the wrong way to solve the initial problem in the first place. I suspect you were tasked with this work while studying `static` member variables, *none* of which appear in this code. Anyway, the actual original problem should be part of your question, as it is relevant.

Comment: Make a class named Fruit with a data member to calculate the number of fruits in a basket. Create two other class named Apples and Mangoes to calculate the number of apples and mangoes in the basket. Print the number of fruits of each type and the total number of fruits in the basket.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need the use of inheritance.
You will use virtual functions.

You will have to store in a vector of pointers to fruit, all the fruits you have.

```
vector<Fruit*> MyFruits;
```

Inside class `Fruit` you will implement a virtual function:

```
virtual int get_num_of_fruits(){}
```

And inside the child classes:

```
int get_num_of_fruits(){
    return nr_child; //nr_apples,nr_mangos etc.
}
```

Then you will have an `int nr_fruits = 0` and add to the number of all the fruits(apples,mangos etc.)

So, `nr_fruits += MyFruits[i]->get_num_of_fruits();` for `i = 0` to `i<MyFruits.size()`

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your example and for simplicity, you can change your `nr_fruits` variable to be static, then initialize it after the class declaration:

```
class Fruit {
    public:
        static int nr_fruits;
        void printTotal() {
            cout << "Total fruits in the basket: " << nr_fruits << endl;
        }
};
int Fruit::nr_fruits = 0;
```

However, without knowing the full scope of the requirements for your program, I think you may want to consider to design a better approach to your problem...

Comment: Problem : Make a class named Fruit with a data member to calculate the number of fruits in a basket. Create two other class named Apples and Mangoes to calculate the number of apples and mangoes in the basket. Print the number of fruits of each type and the total number of fruits in the basket. I didn't use static because it was always asking me to make it a const also, which really confused me as the nr_fruits , the way i need it, will change after intialization. Thanks for showing me the way to initialize it.